# Unión de dos DataFrames con diferentes longitudes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Dispongo de dos DataFrames de una sola columna y cuyos índices de filas son fechas . Quiero unir ambos DataFrame, en uno solo, con el rango de fechas (fecha menor - fecha mayor) en los DataFrames. Intento hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
import pandas as pd

# Primer DataFrame
dicc_df1 = {'Close df1': {Timestamp('2013-12-20 00:00:00'): 9689.900390625,
  Timestamp('2013-12-23 00:00:00'): 9758.400390625,
  Timestamp('2013-12-24 00:00:00'): 9819.5,
  Timestamp('2013-12-27 00:00:00'): 9900.099609375,
  Timestamp('2013-12-30 00:00:00'): 9901.900390625,
  Timestamp('2013-12-31 00:00:00'): 9916.7001953125,
  Timestamp('2014-01-02 00:00:00'): 9760.2998046875,
  Timestamp('2014-01-03 00:00:00'): 9798.0,
  Timestamp('2014-01-06 00:00:00'): 9888.5,
  Timestamp('2014-01-07 00:00:00'): 10178.7001953125,
  Timestamp('2014-01-08 00:00:00'): 10253.599609375}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicc_df1, orient='columns')
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df1 = df1.rename_axis('Date')

# Segundo DataFrame
dicc_df2 = {'Close df2': {Timestamp('2014-01-06 00:00:00'): 9888.5,
  Timestamp('2014-01-07 00:00:00'): 10178.7001953125,
  Timestamp('2014-01-08 00:00:00'): 10253.599609375,
  Timestamp('2014-01-09 00:00:00'): 10234.2001953125,
  Timestamp('2014-01-10 00:00:00'): 10290.599609375,
  Timestamp('2014-01-13 00:00:00'): 10365.5,
  Timestamp('2014-01-14 00:00:00'): 10382.0,
  Timestamp('2014-01-15 00:00:00'): 10525.0,
  Timestamp('2014-01-16 00:00:00'): 10455.5,
  Timestamp('2014-01-17 00:00:00'): 10465.7001953125}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicc_df2, orient='columns')
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df2 = df2.rename_axis('Date')

# Determinar el rango de fechas basado en el DataFrame más grande
start_date = min(df1.index.min(), df2.index.min())
end_date = max(df1.index.max(), df2.index.max())

# Unión de los dos DataFrames
df1 = df1.loc[start_date:end_date].ffill().bfill()
df2 = df2.loc[start_date:end_date].ffill().bfill()
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
df_total
```

Me devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No ha seleccionado un rango con las fechas más antigua y la más reciente. ¿Cuál es el error?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu descripción, lo que buscas hacer es un *full outer join* de los dos dataframes.

Luego de terminar de definirlos, con sus índices, puedes valerte del método `join()` para lograrlo, por ejemplo:

```
df_completo = df1.join(df2, lsuffix="_left", rsuffix="_right", how="outer")
print(df_completo)
```

Me devuelve:

```
               Close df1     Close df2
Date                                  
2013-12-20   9689.900391           NaN
2013-12-23   9758.400391           NaN
2013-12-24   9819.500000           NaN
2013-12-27   9900.099609           NaN
2013-12-30   9901.900391           NaN
2013-12-31   9916.700195           NaN
2014-01-02   9760.299805           NaN
2014-01-03   9798.000000           NaN
2014-01-06   9888.500000   9888.500000
2014-01-07  10178.700195  10178.700195
2014-01-08  10253.599609  10253.599609
2014-01-09           NaN  10234.200195
2014-01-10           NaN  10290.599609
2014-01-13           NaN  10365.500000
2014-01-14           NaN  10382.000000
2014-01-15           NaN  10525.000000
2014-01-16           NaN  10455.500000
2014-01-17           NaN  10465.700195
```

Si observas, no hace falta buscar el rango de fechas, el outer join va a traer todas las fechas que existan en ambos dataframes y para las columnas que no encuentre coincidencia entre ellos va a poner `NaN`.

Otra alternativa es que quieras *concatenar* los DataFrames. Para ello, he cambiado el nombre de la columna en ambos a `Close` y luego he ejecutado el siguiente código:

```
df_completo = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()
print(df_completo)
```

Que arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
                   Close
Date                    
2013-12-20   9689.900391
2013-12-23   9758.400391
2013-12-24   9819.500000
2013-12-27   9900.099609
2013-12-30   9901.900391
2013-12-31   9916.700195
2014-01-02   9760.299805
2014-01-03   9798.000000
2014-01-06   9888.500000
2014-01-07  10178.700195
2014-01-08  10253.599609
2014-01-09  10234.200195
2014-01-10  10290.599609
2014-01-13  10365.500000
2014-01-14  10382.000000
2014-01-15  10525.000000
2014-01-16  10455.500000
2014-01-17  10465.700195
```

Comment: La mejor opción es la que me apuntas con joint, y es la que voy a aplicar . No obstante, como habia encontrado otra que puede servir para los que como yo estamos aprendiendo y necesitamos ver muchas posibiidades de código, la voy a aportar como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la mejor opción es la apuntada por jachguate, aporto esta otra .

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

# Primer DataFrame
dicc_df1 = {
    'Close df1': {
        Timestamp('2013-12-20 00:00:00'): 9689.900390625,
        Timestamp('2013-12-23 00:00:00'): 9758.400390625,
        Timestamp('2013-12-24 00:00:00'): 9819.5,
        Timestamp('2013-12-27 00:00:00'): 9900.099609375,
        Timestamp('2013-12-30 00:00:00'): 9901.900390625,
        Timestamp('2013-12-31 00:00:00'): 9916.7001953125,
        Timestamp('2014-01-02 00:00:00'): 9760.2998046875,
        Timestamp('2014-01-03 00:00:00'): 9798.0,
        Timestamp('2014-01-06 00:00:00'): 9888.5,
        Timestamp('2014-01-07 00:00:00'): 10178.7001953125,
        Timestamp('2014-01-08 00:00:00'): 10253.599609375
    }
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicc_df1, orient='columns')
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df1 = df1.rename_axis('Date')

# Segundo DataFrame
dicc_df2 = {
    'Close df2': {
        Timestamp('2014-01-06 00:00:00'): 9888.5,
        Timestamp('2014-01-07 00:00:00'): 10178.7001953125,
        Timestamp('2014-01-08 00:00:00'): 10253.599609375,
        Timestamp('2014-01-09 00:00:00'): 10234.2001953125,
        Timestamp('2014-01-10 00:00:00'): 10290.599609375,
        Timestamp('2014-01-13 00:00:00'): 10365.5,
        Timestamp('2014-01-14 00:00:00'): 10382.0,
        Timestamp('2014-01-15 00:00:00'): 10525.0,
        Timestamp('2014-01-16 00:00:00'): 10455.5,
        Timestamp('2014-01-17 00:00:00'): 10465.7001953125
    }
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicc_df2, orient='columns')
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df2 = df2.rename_axis('Date')

# Crear DataFrame con rango de fechas completo
start_date = min(df1.index.min(), df2.index.min())
end_date = max(df1.index.max(), df2.index.max())
idx = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
df_combined = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)

# Combinar DataFrames y solucionar NaN
df_combined = pd.concat([df_combined, df1, df2], axis=1)
df_combined = df_combined.ffill().bfill()

df_combined.info()
```